# How to add toggle for tables in PowerBI Desktop

Tags: drop-down-menu, toggle, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a graph with the data from a web query. I have 2 different scenario added as different tables. I want to create a toggle for the tables (15_3 Millions and 20_3 Millions). How will I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a slicer. I use one when I need to show just one location.